# NSDateFormatter not returning correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am parsing an XML file and I'm trying to bring it into data that I can use in my iOS App.

I have an NSMutableString called elementDate

If I read the XML file in and do….

```
NSLog(@"Read date: %@", elementDate):
```

I get

Read date: 2013-12-31

which is what I expect.  But I need to now convert this to an NSDate

So I declare a dateFormatter

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [dateFormatter setCalendar:calendar];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

And then I do a

```
NSLog(@"Date From String: %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:elementDate]);
```

The result is:

Date From String: (null)

What simple thing am I missing?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%u", [elementDate length]) ;` show us the length of elementDate.

Comment: Well, there's no need to set the calendar, but it shouldn't do any harm.  As Kudo suggests, there may be some garbage attached to either end of the date string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code runs fine.  No need to set the calendar as the commenter suggests.  I suspect that you've picked up some whitespace in the date string during the xml parse.  Try

```
NSString *trimmed = [elementDate stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"Date From String: %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:trimmed]);
```

Comment: Yup.  That was it.  There was a whitespace character in there.  Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: Yeah, it's typical for XML values to have, in particular, newline characters and tabs with them, unless you use the XML parser options to get rid of whitespace.